# Unable to Connect to Cloud SQL proxy with Ghost CMS deployed on Cloud Run via Unix Socket

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-sql, knex.js, google-cloud-run, ghost-blog

I followed the [guide](https://parondeau.com/blog/self-hosting-ghost-gcp) to connect Ghost-Cloud-Run-Service with Cloud-SQL.

But, following is the error that I am getting:

```
 at /var/lib/ghost/versions/5.25.2/node_modules/knex-migrator/lib/database.js:57:19
  at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/lib/ghost/versions/5.25.2/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:101:31)
  Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
 "Unknown database error"
```

I have cross checked and all the value of my env variables are correct.
Also, I found that Ghost has removed the [socket](https://ghost.org/docs/changes/#misc) support for version 5.XX. And the Ghost Version that I am using is 5.25.2
Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to connect to a CloudSQL in Cloud Run with the public IP is using sockets and the instance connection name, if Socket is removed from Ghost I recommend connecting via private IP using Serverless VPC Access

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run#private-ip

In this way, you could use the private IP for the instance as any MySQL database.

Example of config.json of Ghost

```
"database": {
  "client": "mysql",
  "connection": {
    "host": "[PRIVATE_IP_CLOUD_SQL]",
    "port": 3306,
    "user": "your_database_user",
    "password": "your_database_password",
    "database": "your_database_name"
  }
}
```

In this example the Only SSL connections on the CloudSQL is disabled, if you need encrypted connections you need to add the SSL section:

```
"ssl": {
       "cert": "<database_cert>",
       "ca": "<database_ca>",
       "key": "<database_key>"
}
```

Example here https://github.com/behoyh/ghost/blob/master/data/config.production.json